# What does a pointer variable do?

Tags: c++

The question is to find the output of the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int arr[]={6,3,8,10,4,6,7};
  int *ptr=arr,i;
  cout<<++*ptr++<<'@';
  i=arr[3]-arr[2];
  cout<<++*(ptr+i)<<'@'<<'\n';
  cout<<++i+*ptr++<<'@';
  cout<<*ptr++<<'@'<<'\n';
  for(;i>=0;i-=2)
      cout<<arr[i]<<'@';
  return 0;
}
```

The output for the above program is:

> 7@11@
>
> 6@8@
>
> 11@3@

I know when a pointer is used like this : `*ptr=&var;` it stores the address of the variable `var` in the pointer variable `ptr`.

These are my questions:

1. What does `*ptr=arr[];` do? Where `ptr` is declared as an integer and `arr` is an integer array?
2. What does `*ptr=a;` do if `ptr` and `a` are declared as integer variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does `*ptr=arr;` Where `ptr` is declared as an integer and `arr` is an integer array?

Set `ptr` to point to first element of array `arr`. Read more in [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

The declarations are these:

```
int arr[]={6,3,8,10,4,6,7}; // declare array 'arr'
int *ptr // declare pointer to `int` 'ptr'
```

> What does `*ptr=a;` do if `ptr` and `a` are declared as integer variables?

What you say, in code is this:

```
int ptr, a;
*ptr=a;
```

which, will produce an error, like this:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:4:4: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
    4 |   *ptr=a;
      |    ^~~
```

Comment: You are welcome @Sujit, you asked a nice question, +1. Please make sure to read the linked question I provided..

Answer (score 0):

1. `int *ptr=arr` both declares `ptr` as an `int` pointer, and assigns to `ptr` the address of the first integer in `arr`.
2. `*ptr=a` assigns the value of `a` to the pointee of `ptr`, namely to the integer that `ptr` points to.

Answer (score 0):

1. `*ptr = arr;` Gets the address of the first element in `arr.`
2. `*ptr = a;` Assigns the value of `a` to the integer that `ptr` is pointing to.

Comment: Be careful about #1, the author of the question forgot to mention that it is actually `int *ptr = arr;` as part of the declaration of `ptr`.